# How do I return the values of a function that's called by an event listener?

Tags: javascript, function, return, coordinates, addeventlistener

I want the coordinates calculated by "getPosition" to be available for use with other functions so that I don't have to write the rest of the code that uses x and y within getPosition.

I know I can use something like return {posX: x, posY: y}; to retrieve both values from the function but I don't know how to make them available outside of getPosition.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

  function init()
  {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);
  }

   function getPosition(event)
  {
    var x = new Number();
    var y = new Number();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    if (event.x != undefined && event.y != undefined)
    {
      x = event.x;
      y = event.y;
    }
    else // Firefox method to get the position
    {
      x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
          document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
          document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
    y -= canvas.offsetTop;

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a closure and put your variables x and y and the functions that use them in there:

```
(function(){
  var _x = 0;
  var _y = 0;

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

  function init()
  {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);
  }

   function getPosition(event)
  {
    var x = new Number();
    var y = new Number();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    if (event.x != undefined && event.y != undefined)
    {
      x = event.x;
      y = event.y;
    }
    else // Firefox method to get the position
    {
      x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
          document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
          document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
    y -= canvas.offsetTop;

    //Save x and y for later
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
  }
})();
```

Comment: I tested with alert("x: " + _x + "  y: " + _y); right after the getPosition function and I get x: 0 and y: 0. It doesn't seem to be "listening" to the click event, I don't think the getPosition function is being called, x and y aren't modified. Is there something else missing?